# access properties/method via the __get() magic method

Tags: php, oop

how can i access the second property or method in this statement

```
$this->test->hello();
```

In my `__get()` I can only figure out how to figure out what the `test` property is. I want to be also be able to capture the 'hello' method call. and do some dynamic things with it.

So in short if I type

```
$this->test->hello()
```

I want to `echo` each segment

```
echo $propert // test
echo $method //hello
```

The issue is that my test is being used to instantiate a new class object from an outside class. The method `hello` belongs to the `test` class object.

I want to capture the method within my `__get()`.

How can i do this?

EDIT:

```
public function __get($name)
        {
            if ($name == 'system' || $name == 'sys') {

                $_class = 'System_Helper';

            } else {

                foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $_property => $_value) {

                    if ($name == $_property)
                        $_class = $name;
                }
            }

            $classname = '\\System\\' . ucfirst($_class);
            $this->$_class = new $classname();

            //$rClass = new \ReflectionClass($this->$_class);
            $rClass = get_class_methods($this->$_class);
            foreach($rClass as $k => $v)
            echo $v."\n";
            //print_r($rClass);

            return $this->$_class;
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `__get()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are after some kind of proxy class, this might suit your needs.

```
class ObjectProxy {
    public $object;

    public function __construct($object) {
        $this->object = $object;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if (!property_exists($this->object, $name)) {
            return "Error: property ($name) does not exist";
        }
        return $this->object->$name;
    }

    public function __call($name, $args) {
        if (!method_exists($this->object, $name)) {
            return "Error: method ($name) does not exist";
        }
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->object, $name), $args);
    }
}

class A {
    public $prop = 'Some prop';

    public function hello() {
        return 'Hello, world!';
    }
}

class B {
    public function __get($name) {
        if (!isset($this->$name)) {
            $class_name = ucfirst($name);
            $this->$name = new ObjectProxy(new $class_name);
        }
        return $this->$name;
    }
}
$b = new B();
var_dump($b->a->hello());
var_dump($b->a->prop);
var_dump($b->a->foo);
var_dump($b->a->bar());
```

Output:

```
string 'Hello, world!' (length=13)
string 'Some prop' (length=9)
string 'Error: property (foo) does not exist' (length=36)
string 'Error: method (bar) does not exist' (length=34)
```

Example:

http://ideone.com/dMna6

It could be easily extend for other magic methods like `__set`, `__callStatic`, `__isset`, `__invoke`, etc.

Comment: close, but i was seeing if there was a way to do this all within the same class while calling another class. I was trying to see if i could catch any method does not exist errors within one parent class rather than having a __call in the 'A' class

Comment: @Eli, there is not `__call` in the example I gave, you might need to explain your question better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `__call` instead of `__get`.  Also, don't.

Comment: @MikePurcell using `__call` is bad for a variety of reasons .. it's slow and unclear, and it breaks the interface.  However, it is available anyway.

Comment: Ahhh, I am inclined to agree. I do use it in rare instances such as logging strings to a log file where I can specify the `LOG_LEVEL` and have it look like `$log->debug($message)`

Answer (score 0):

The object you instantiated for `$this` will use the `__get` magic method to create the object (as a property) `test`. The object stored at `$this->test` needs to implement the `__call` magic method to use `hello()` if it's not defined

Comment: i could do a __call() with in my test class, but I wanted to capture the method before it gets passed to the Test class.

Comment: Catch it with $this? I think you might be misunderstanding how chaining works in php

Comment: i know how chaining works, I was just wondering if there was a way to dissect the chain into segments before executing.